# Jfrog Artifactory Garbage Collection

Tags: artifactory

How can we programmatically trigger Garbage Collection on JFrog Artifactory? We see it is set a background task of artifactory. Couldn't find its API in their REST API documentation.

~NR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why its undocumented (will take care of that) but you can trigger gc manually with:

```
POST /api/system/storage/gc
```

Comment: currently the docs are availbale here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RunGarbageCollection

Answer (score 0):

curl -u admin:***** -k -v -X POST  -H "Content-Type: text/plain" https://artifactoryfqdn/artifactory/api/system/storage/gc